# Materialize is not working with React, Webpacka. jQuery is not extended

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, webpack, materialize

I have a problem with using materialize-css with React. I have built it using Webpack and Babel. The problem is:

> TypeError: $(...).parallax is not a function
>   TypeError: $(...).material_chip is not a function
>   TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
>   etc.

It is my React class:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'materialize-css';
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';

class AwesomeComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    onLike () {
        $('.modal').modal();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="modal1" className="modal">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <h4>Modal Header</h4>
                        <p>A bunch of text</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-footer">
                        <a href="#!" className=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a className="waves-effect waves-light btn" onClick={this.onLike}>
                    <i className="material-icons left">
                        cloud
                    </i>
                    Like cloud
                </a>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default AwesomeComponent;
```

This is a part of my webpack.config.js which imports jQuery:

```
plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        })
```

This is a part of my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "materialize-css": "^0.98.0",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Help me please, I have tried everything.

I have debug it. It adds plugins (.modal for example) to $ prototype, but somehow the functions disappeared when I want to use it in the class.

At the end this is a stacktrace:

> TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function[Learn More] bundle.js:44497:14
>     onLike
>     bound onLike
>     ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback
>     executeDispatch
>     executeDispatchesInOrder 
>     executeDispatchesAndRelease
>     executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel
>     forEach 
>     forEachAccumulated
>     EventPluginHub.processEventQueue
>     runEventQueueInBatch
>     ReactEventEmitterMixin.handleTopLevel
>     handleTopLevelImpl
>     TransactionImpl.perform
>     ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates
>     batchedUpdates
>     ReactEventListener.dispatchEvent
>     bound

Comment: Did you ever get the modal to show?  I'm having a similar issue except that I don't get an error when open is called.  Nothing happens at all.  I have the same setup as you.  The answer below did not work either.  Also, the material-react Modal is broken right now.

Answer (score 1):

For others with the same problem.

Do not use in webpack.config.js webpack.ProvidePlugin and do not import $ or jQuery. Materialize will provide it for you.

```
plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        })
```

To do it use below code on top of you jsx file:

```
import 'materialize-css';
```

And do not forgot about proper loaders, it is important for Materialize:

```
loaders : [
            {
                test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?importLoaders=1', 'sass-loader'],
                exclude: ['node_modules']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?importLoaders=1'],
                exclude: ['node_modules']
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ['babel-loader', 'babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015'],
            }
        ]
```